# Understanding "not valid in the context where it is used" error using SELECT in SQL

Tags: sql, debugging, db2, inner-join

In a Coursera course, there are 2 tables `employees` and `departments`. Their schemas are reproduced below.

I get no error if I run

```
SELECT *
FROM employees E, departments D 
WHERE E.DEP_ID = D.DEPT_ID_DEP;
```

But if I run

```
SELECT employees.EMP_ID, departments.DEPT_NAME
FROM employees E, departments D 
WHERE E.DEP_ID = D.DEPT_ID_DEP;
```

I get an error

```
Error message
"EMPLOYEES.EMP_ID" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.26.14
```

> Both code snippets are from the course itself, which makes no indication that either snippet should produce an error. Could you please help me understand why the second snippet produces an error, and how to fix it?

--
**EDIT**

I get a similar error if I run

```
SELECT E.EMP_ID, D.DEP_ID_DEP
FROM employees E, departments D 
WHERE E.DEP_ID = D.DEPT_ID_DEP;
```

--

p.s. Schema for `employees`:

[image]

Schema for `departments`

[image]

Comment: Don't use a course that is teaching you to use commas in the `FROM` clause.  `JOIN` has been SQL standard syntax since the 1990s.

Answer (score 0):

The `FROM` clause of the query assigns aliases to the tables. If you want to refer to the tables anywhere in the other clauses of the query (`WHERE`, `SELECT`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and so on), you need to use the aliases rather than the table names:

```
SELECT E.EMP_ID, D.DEPT_NAME
FROM employees E
INNER JOIN departments D ON E.DEP_ID = D.DEPT_ID_DEP;
```

Note that I changed the code to use standard joins rather than old-school, implicit joins. This is not related to your question, but I would recommend consistently using this standard syntax in your queries. Implicit joins are legacy syntax that should be avoided in new code.

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar errors if I used aliases. Please see the edit. I also ran your code and got this error: "D.DEPT_NAME" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.26.14

Comment: I'm running the SQL queries on IBM Db2. Could the fact that implicit join is a legacy thing the reason for the error?

Comment: @yurnero: that's very suprising. This is standard and simple SQL, that all databases that I know do support (including DB2 of course). Maybe you are not running the query exactly as given, or your included it in another, bigger query?

Comment: This might be an authorization issue, as documented here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql0206n-not-valid-context-where-it-used-error-when-testing-query-subject-framework-manager

Comment: Hi, I copy-and-pasted your code. Thanks for all the help. I will ask the course provider when I have a chance. Thanks for warning me about implicit join.